# Should I use a possibly invalid Schengen visa for France?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have been issued a multiple-entry type C Schengen visa from the Italian embassy. But it is not valid anymore [OP: "already"], only from October 2013 to February 2014. if I am planning to go to Paris in January 2015, can I used this visa or I should apply for another Schengen visa from the French embassy?

Comment: You wrote "It is not valid already" - do you mean that you received a visa a few months ago but it carries the wrong date, or do you mean that you received the visa in 2013 and it has expired?

Answer (score 10):

Your visa expired in February 2014. You cannot use that visa to enter the Schengen area after that date, so you must apply for a new one.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is, you'll arrive at the airport, go to immigration, and show them your passport. They'll look for a valid visa. You won't have one as your visa (from their point of view) has expired.  They'll then turn you away at the border.

If you even get that far - the airline when you leave will likely stop you from travelling in the event you don't have a valid visa.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests the OP is currently within the Schengen area (e.g. Italy), nor is there any hint that "they've made an error". What you imply is not entirely impossible, but based on the question, the most straightforward interpretation simply seems to be that the OP, an extra-Schengen resident, has travelled to the Schengen area (probably Italy) before, based on a visa they got back then, and returned home, and now, they'd like to return to the Schengen area (this time, to France), but their old visa has expired meanwhile. Am I missing anything in the question? :-S

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: an earlier version of the question could be interpreted (likely wrongly, IMHO) that there has been an error on the side of the embassy.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yeah question changed slightly. I've altered my answer.  Main point stands - if the visa is not valid for the dates he travels, he's not getting it accepted.